# How secure is pdf password protection?

Tags: encryption, pdf

I'm assuming PDF password protection uses encryption. How secure are the methods used? Can it be easily cracked or is it more in line with modern GPG encryption in terms of strength?

Comment: Security is different for different product. An answer is found on Adobe's FAQ: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/securing-pdfs-passwords.html

Comment: GPG is an asymmetric encryption system, while PDF encryption uses symmetric encryption. So, no it's not comparable with GPG, they have very different threat model.